# nodejs cron job(AWS) - How can i run cron job in multiple timezones

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, timezone

Lets consider we have 3 user( user count may change dynamically in Realtime ) located in different places with below time zones.

user1 - Australia/Adelaide

user2 - Asia/Kolkata

user3 - Europe/Paris

...........

...........

I want to send an email to all the available users at some point of time every day, so that email should deliver at 2pm to all the users to their respective time zones

I can able to do it for single time zone but not multiple using single cron job

how can i get it work for multiple time zone using single cron job?

Answer (score 0):

based on [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) put the timezone as parameter for `CronJob`

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
let timzones = ["America/Los_Angeles", "Asia/Kolkata"];

timzones.forEach(timezone=>{
  var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
    console.log('You will see this message every second');
  }, null, true, timezone);
  job.start();
})
```

Comment: I'm using AWS Job scheduler (serverless) to run cron job, and time zones may push or pop from array every day